# Shiny: How to directly use lists defined in Server in UI

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rstudio, visnetwork

I am building a network analysis using visNetwork package in Shiny and wondering if there is a way to directly use items defined in Server in UI.

As the code below, for **selectInput** in **UI**, I'd like to call a list **"nodes$id"**, which is a **column of dataframe "nodes"** defined in **Shiny server**.

It did not work as **lists called in UI** have to be **pre-defined in R** instead of **Shiny Server**.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    nodes <- data.frame(id = 2:4)
    edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,3), to = c(2,4))

    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visNodes(color = "blue")
  })


  observe({
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visFocus(id = input$Focus, scale = 4)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",
                  nodes$id)
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you would like to show the node id's generated in the server, in the select input? Check out `updateSelectInput()`. If you want to pass other values to the ui you can check out sendCustomMessage(). https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/server-to-client-custom-messages.html

Comment: Thank you Sada. I would like to show the nodes ids in selected input. The nodes & nodes ids are generated in the Server. In my real project, nodes are directly queried out from the database, so there would be more nodes consistently as new data coming into the database. updateSelectInput() seems not working in this case. Do you have any thoughts on this? I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for illustrative purposes. But as mentioned in the comments above, your functionality can be achieved with a updateSelectInput and your database can be queried in a reactivePoll which searches for new nodes added to the network. Here is an example where nodes are added every minute to the network.

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)
library(lubridate)

#Values to initialize
nodes <- data.frame(id = 2:4)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,3), to = c(2,4))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  data = reactivePoll(1000,session,
                      checkFunc = function(){
                        # SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table

                        #For illustration it triggeres every minute
                        minute(Sys.time())
                      },
                      valueFunc = function(){
                        #SELECT * FROM table

                        nodes <<- rbind(nodes,data.frame(id = minute(Sys.time())))
                        edges <<- rbind(edges,data.frame(from = c(minute(Sys.time())),to = 2))
                        return(list(nodes = nodes,edges = edges))
                      }
  )

  #Use the dataframe of nodes you got above to set the updateSelectInput
  observe({
    req(data())
    updateSelectInput(session,"Focus",choices = data()$nodes$id)
  })


  output$network_proxy_nodes <- renderVisNetwork({
    # minimal example
    visNetwork(data()$nodes, data()$edges) %>% visNodes(color = "blue")
  })


  observe({
    req(input$Focus)
    visNetworkProxy("network_proxy_nodes") %>%
      visFocus(id = input$Focus, scale = 4)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("Focus", "Focus on node :",nodes$id)
    ),
    column(
      width = 8,
      visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_nodes", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```